How can I produce \twoheaddownarrow?
I found the solution for the left case but am not sufficiently versed in latex to use it to define the downcase. Can you help to obtain \twoheaddownarrow ?

If you are using Unicode math then you have \twoheaddownarrow ready to use. For example in OpTeX: \fontfam[lm] $\twoheaddownarrow$ \bye

This question is similar to: How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can superimpose a clipped and raised \downarrow.
I also provide \twoheaduparrow.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twoheaddownarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\twoheaddownarrow@\relax}}
\newcommand{\twoheaddownarrow@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\downarrow$}%
  \vphantom{\copy\z@}% keep the bounding box
  \ooalign{\copy\z@\cr\hidewidth\clipdownarrow@{#1}\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\clipdownarrow@}[1]{%
  \raisebox{0.25\ht\z@}{\clipbox{-3pt 0pt -3pt {0.5\height}}{\copy\z@}}%
}
\newcommand{\twoheaduparrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\twoheaduparrow@\relax}}
\newcommand{\twoheaduparrow@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\uparrow$}%
  \vphantom{\copy\z@}% keep the bounding box
  \ooalign{\copy\z@\cr\hidewidth\clipuparrow@{#1}\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\clipuparrow@}[1]{%
  \raisebox{0.1\ht\z@}{\clipbox{-3pt {0.65\height} -3pt 0pt}{\copy\z@}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\downarrow B\twoheaddownarrow C\twoheaduparrow D$

$\scriptstyle A\downarrow B\twoheaddownarrow C\twoheaduparrow D$

\end{document}



Thank you. Much appreciated.

Just for fun, try with:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\rotatebox{270}{%
\xymatrix@C=1.5pc{\ar@{->>}[r]& }
}%
\end{document}

Thanks to @Sebastino; How to draw a surjective (double-headed) arrow between two nodes in TikZ?


Many thanks. Great to have an alternative
